# Why 'amp;' is include in link in many parts of links('a') that I'm trying to scrape using BeautifulSoup in phyton? whats the better way to remove it?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am using `findAll('a')` or the variations of it to extract a particular tag or class but I'm getting 'amp;' in between the link in many parts.

**Example:**
The two links the actual and error('amp;') one
https://help.cybonline.co.uk/system/selfservice.controller?CONFIGURATION=1113&PARTITION_ID=1&secureFlag=true&TIMEZONE_OFFSET=&CMD=VIEW_ARTICLE&ARTICLE_ID=14311&CUST_PREV_CMD=null

https://help.cybonline.co.uk/system/selfservice.controller?CONFIGURATION=111)3&PARTITION_ID=1&secureFlag=true&TIMEZONE_OFFSET=&CMD=VIEW_ARTICLE&ARTICLE_ID=14311&CUST_PREV_CMD=null

```
"selfservice.controller?CONFIGURATION=1113&amp;PARTITION_ID=1&amp;secureFlag=false&amp;TIMEZONE_OFFSET=&amp;CMD=VIEW_ARTICLE&amp;ARTICLE_ID=14271&amp;CUST_PREV_CMD=BROWSE_TOPIC"
```

I can get rid of it using regex, but is there a better way to do it?

The website I'm having a problem with is [cybonline](https://help.cybonline.co.uk/system/selfservice.controller?CONFIGURATION=1113&PARTITION_ID=1&secureFlag=true&TIMEZONE_OFFSET=&CMD=BROWSE_TOPIC&TOPIC_ID=55956)

Comment: That is href value.Why you would like to remove any reason?

Comment: The actual links doesn't have 'amp;' in the link, this may be included due to an error in beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see that problem at all with lxml. Can you try running the following?

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
base_url = 'https://help.cybonline.co.uk/system/'
r = requests.get('https://help.cybonline.co.uk/system/selfservice.controller?CONFIGURATION=1113&PARTITION_ID=1&secureFlag=true&TIMEZONE_OFFSET=&CMD=BROWSE_TOPIC&TOPIC_ID=55956')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')

links = [base_url + item['href'] for item in soup.select('.articleAnchor')]
print(links)
```

If not, you can use replace

```
base_url + item['href'].replace('amp;', '')
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, your code works perfectly. You have any idea why amp; was included when I was trying to extract using findall('a')?

Comment: I don’t know what find does in the background. I stick with select and lxml and I see cleaner results consistently.

Answer (score 0):

If you want remove that `&` value you can simply use replace while fetching the value.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html=requests.get("https://help.cybonline.co.uk/system/selfservice.controller?CONFIGURATION=1113&PARTITION_ID=1&secureFlag=true&TIMEZONE_OFFSET=&CMD=BROWSE_TOPIC&TOPIC_ID=55956").text
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

for a in soup.find_all('a' ,class_='articleAnchor'):
    link=a['href'].replace('&' , '')
    print(link)
```

OR

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html=requests.get("https://help.cybonline.co.uk/system/selfservice.controller?CONFIGURATION=1113&PARTITION_ID=1&secureFlag=true&TIMEZONE_OFFSET=&CMD=BROWSE_TOPIC&TOPIC_ID=55956").text
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('a.articleAnchor'):
    link=a['href'].replace('&' , '')
    print(link)
```